# How to get whole code deployment history in Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, logging, deployment, azure-web-app-service

Need to get the code deployment data for my Azure WebApp. Since the App has been accessed by multiple team members and I am unable to trace When , Who(Name or email if of the person) has done the deployment with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the operations for a deployment through the Azure portal.

1.From the resource group, you could notice the [status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb3l2.png) of the **Deployments**, click in you would see all deployments history.

2.Go to your **App Service**, click **Activity log** and set the `Timespan` in which you think the deployment might have occurred (with a maximum of 90 days in the past).

Hope these could help you, if you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: I did already, However I was only able to get one common log i.e "Get Web App Publishing Profile" for every hour. I am pretty much sure we are not deploying any code with this time span.

Comment: In Activity log default Timespan is Last 6 hours, you could choose the Timespan you need.And did you try the status of deployment, it could also show some informations.  You also could refer to this link to get information with different way.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit